# How to export csv/excel in QGIS3.0 model processor?

Tags: qgis, csv, qgis-processing

In the model processor for QGIS 3.0, how do I have the attribute table export as an excel? I have five different outputs/excels I need and would like to automate the process instead of needing to gobto each layer individually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd guess you just have to set the outcome of the specific processes as final ones, then QGis (at least 2.x) will ask you where to save it.

Comment: I see what you are saying. That makes compete sense! It would be nice if it just had an "export to Csv" like arcmap does.

Answer (score 0):

Since QGIS 3.18 there is an algorithm called ***Export to spreadsheet*** that does just that and can be used in models. Allows you to export one or more layers across multiple sheets, overwrite them, or add them to existing files. Supported output formats are Excel (.xlsx) and Open Document Spreadsheet ('.ods').

[image]