# Missing "Save features as" in Processing Modeler in QGIS 3.10

Tags: qgis, pyqgis-3

Is possible in Processing Modeler use "Export" - "Save features as"?

### Model schema:

[image]

### Generated code:

```py
from qgis.core import QgsProcessing
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingAlgorithm
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingMultiStepFeedback
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink
import processing


class MyExampleModel(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):

    def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer('inputlayer', 'input layer', types=[QgsProcessing.TypeVectorPoint], defaultValue=None))
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink('ResultCsvLayer', 'result CSV layer', type=QgsProcessing.TypeVectorAnyGeometry, createByDefault=True, defaultValue=None))

    def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, model_feedback):
        # Use a multi-step feedback, so that individual child algorithm progress reports are adjusted for the
        # overall progress through the model
        feedback = QgsProcessingMultiStepFeedback(1, model_feedback)
        results = {}
        outputs = {}

        # Add field to attributes table
        alg_params = {
            'FIELD_LENGTH': 10,
            'FIELD_NAME': 'example_field',
            'FIELD_PRECISION': 0,
            'FIELD_TYPE': 0,
            'INPUT': parameters['inputlayer'],
            'OUTPUT': parameters['ResultCsvLayer']
        }
        outputs['AddFieldToAttributesTable'] = processing.run('qgis:addfieldtoattributestable', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)
        results['ResultCsvLayer'] = outputs['AddFieldToAttributesTable']['OUTPUT']
        return results

    def name(self):
        return 'my example model'

    def displayName(self):
        return 'my example model'

    def group(self):
        return 'example group'

    def groupId(self):
        return ''

    def createInstance(self):
        return MyExampleModel()
```

### Model exported format:

```xml
<!DOCTYPE model>
<Option type="Map">
  <Option type="Map" name="children">
    <Option type="Map" name="qgis:addfieldtoattributestable_1">
      <Option type="bool" value="true" name="active"/>
      <Option name="alg_config"/>
      <Option type="QString" value="qgis:addfieldtoattributestable" name="alg_id"/>
      <Option type="QString" value="Add field to attributes table" name="component_description"/>
      <Option type="double" value="443" name="component_pos_x"/>
      <Option type="double" value="506" name="component_pos_y"/>
      <Option name="dependencies"/>
      <Option type="QString" value="qgis:addfieldtoattributestable_1" name="id"/>
      <Option type="Map" name="outputs">
        <Option type="Map" name="result CSV layer">
          <Option type="QString" value="qgis:addfieldtoattributestable_1" name="child_id"/>
          <Option type="QString" value="result CSV layer" name="component_description"/>
          <Option type="double" value="448" name="component_pos_x"/>
          <Option type="double" value="585" name="component_pos_y"/>
          <Option type="invalid" name="default_value"/>
          <Option type="bool" value="false" name="mandatory"/>
          <Option type="QString" value="result CSV layer" name="name"/>
          <Option type="QString" value="OUTPUT" name="output_name"/>
        </Option>
      </Option>
      <Option type="bool" value="true" name="outputs_collapsed"/>
      <Option type="bool" value="true" name="parameters_collapsed"/>
      <Option type="Map" name="params">
        <Option type="List" name="FIELD_LENGTH">
          <Option type="Map">
            <Option type="int" value="2" name="source"/>
            <Option type="int" value="10" name="static_value"/>
          </Option>
        </Option>
        <Option type="List" name="FIELD_NAME">
          <Option type="Map">
            <Option type="int" value="2" name="source"/>
            <Option type="QString" value="example_field" name="static_value"/>
          </Option>
        </Option>
        <Option type="List" name="FIELD_PRECISION">
          <Option type="Map">
            <Option type="int" value="2" name="source"/>
            <Option type="int" value="0" name="static_value"/>
          </Option>
        </Option>
        <Option type="List" name="FIELD_TYPE">
          <Option type="Map">
            <Option type="int" value="2" name="source"/>
            <Option type="int" value="0" name="static_value"/>
          </Option>
        </Option>
        <Option type="List" name="INPUT">
          <Option type="Map">
            <Option type="QString" value="inputlayer" name="parameter_name"/>
            <Option type="int" value="0" name="source"/>
          </Option>
        </Option>
      </Option>
    </Option>
  </Option>
  <Option name="help"/>
  <Option name="modelVariables"/>
  <Option type="QString" value="example group" name="model_group"/>
  <Option type="QString" value="my example model" name="model_name"/>
  <Option type="Map" name="parameterDefinitions">
    <Option type="Map" name="inputlayer">
      <Option type="List" name="data_types">
        <Option type="int" value="0"/>
      </Option>
      <Option type="invalid" name="default"/>
      <Option type="QString" value="input layer" name="description"/>
      <Option type="int" value="0" name="flags"/>
      <Option name="metadata"/>
      <Option type="QString" value="inputlayer" name="name"/>
      <Option type="QString" value="vector" name="parameter_type"/>
    </Option>
    <Option type="Map" name="qgis:addfieldtoattributestable_1:result CSV layer">
      <Option type="bool" value="true" name="create_by_default"/>
      <Option type="int" value="-1" name="data_type"/>
      <Option type="invalid" name="default"/>
      <Option type="QString" value="result CSV layer" name="description"/>
      <Option type="int" value="0" name="flags"/>
      <Option name="metadata"/>
      <Option type="QString" value="qgis:addfieldtoattributestable_1:result CSV layer" name="name"/>
      <Option type="QString" value="sink" name="parameter_type"/>
      <Option type="bool" value="true" name="supports_non_file_outputs"/>
    </Option>
  </Option>
  <Option type="Map" name="parameters">
    <Option type="Map" name="inputlayer">
      <Option type="QString" value="inputlayer" name="component_description"/>
      <Option type="double" value="443" name="component_pos_x"/>
      <Option type="double" value="418" name="component_pos_y"/>
      <Option type="QString" value="inputlayer" name="name"/>
    </Option>
  </Option>
</Option>
```

### Info about QGIS:

### [image]
Summary:

I want to specify result CSV layer as CSV file with semicolon delimiter in model without user typing settings in file export system menu.

Comment: Everything you set as a final outcome will ask you for a location to be saved at once you run the model. Does this answer your question?

Comment: I want save CSV file with specific "layerOptions" without typing export setting

Comment: Then please edit your question accordingly and add, what you tried so far.

Comment: I am added some details about this questions, is sufficient?

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/337693/exporting-result-of-qgis-model-to-csv